# how to assign custom time to a string when converting it to dateTime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I get a string as `"Start:6/23/2020 End:7/31/2020"` and for converting it into specific datetime format I have written the following code where I have removed the `Start:` and `End:`  and while converting I want to assign the time as `11:59:59 PM` to end the end date. How can we do it?

```
if (s.FilterBy.Equals("Submit Date"))
            {
                s.SearchTerm = s.SearchTerm.Replace("Start:", "").Replace("End:", "");
                string[] date = s.SearchTerm.Split(' ');
                DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date[0]);
                DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date[1]);
                var idList = accessBrokerService.GetFileteredIds(s.SearchTerm);
                // StringComparison comp = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
                requestListItems = requestListItems.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.SearchTerm)
                || (x.RequestDate >= startDate && x.RequestDate <= endDate)
                || idList.Any(list => list.Equals(x.RequestItemKey))).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: There might be easier ways, but `endDate = endDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);` should be pretty self explanatory. -- otherwise, you could just `AddDays(1)` and then change `<=` to strictly `<` making it `x.RequestDate < endDate`

Comment: Oh, btw. I interpreted `11:59:59` as pm. I guess the most specific way would be: `endDate = endDate.Add(new TimeSpan(23,59,59));`, note the 24h notation.

Comment: yes i wanted it for 11.59.59 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was suggested the comments I tried out adding `endDate = endDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);` and it worked.

And this is how my code looks like now

```
   if (s.FilterBy.Equals("Submit Date"))
                {
                    s.SearchTerm = s.SearchTerm.Replace("Start:", "").Replace("End:", "");
                    string[] date = s.SearchTerm.Split(' ');
                    DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date[0]);
                    DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date[1]);
                    endDate = endDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
                    var idList = accessBrokerService.GetFileteredIds(s.SearchTerm);
                    // StringComparison comp = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
                    requestListItems = requestListItems.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.SearchTerm)
                    || (x.RequestDate >= startDate && x.RequestDate <= endDate)
                    || idList.Any(list => list.Equals(x.RequestItemKey))).ToList();
                }
```